# How to play audio byte array in C#

Tags: c#, audio, stream

I am trying to play an incomming stream of bytes comming from Bluetooth. I tried MediaPlayer, but the documentation says, it can only play full byte arrays(whole file), but not streaming bytes. The bytes are being read like this.

example:

123

123456

123456789

Also found a AudioTrack, but that has a couple of seconds of nothing and then something like music for a second and than only "fart" sounds from there. If anybody knows something, it would be appreciated.

---

Ok I will rephrase, the numbers are only an example, if I put a tring inside it would read it like:
This
This is 
This is a stri
This is a string.
(something like that).
I am getting it from the Bluetooth readlike this, but I would like to play it using AudioTrack, but it only plays a music 1s and than "farts", I already use MediaPlayer, to play an entire song, but MediaPlayer can only play entire song(so I have read).

```
AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(Android.Media.Stream.Music, 11025, ChannelOut.Mono, Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit, 0x1000, AudioTrackMode.Stream);

while (mmInStream.IsDataAvailable())
{
    numberOfBytesRead = mmInStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
    audioTrack.Write(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
    audioTrack.Play();
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what makes this question different from your previous 3? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59074841/receiving-byte-stream-from-bluetooth-correct, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59125914/streaming-audio-through-bluetooth, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59143657/how-to-play-a-stream-of-audio-bytes). If it is indeed different, you need to include some more detail, perhaps give us what you have as a starting point.

Comment: One possibility is your audio codec on the machine is not compatible with the bluetooth audio.  Before trying code in c# take you media player on machine and see if you get real audio.

Comment: I don't quite follow what the numbers in your example represent or how you're getting them. Could you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?